# Auth errors and callout errors in Scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, error, login, http

I have an app that makes API Rest calls to my cratch org.  Till yesterday everything was working fine. 
Yesterday I have configured scheduled apex class job to run in the night.
But when checked the result I have found the strange response/error.

The code is:

```
Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v47.0/composite/tree/DatedConversionRate/');
        req.setBody(requestBody);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setMethod('POST');

        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

And it was working fine.  But starting from today I started getting the next response:

> 17:10:38:747 CALLOUT_REQUEST
>   [120]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://nosoftware-efficiency-6832-dev-ed.cs83.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/composite/tree/DatedConversionRate/,
>   Method=POST] 17:10:38:776 CALLOUT_RESPONSE
>   [120]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Temporary Redirect, StatusCode=307]

The body of the response:

> The URL has moved [here](https://nosoftware-efficiency-6832-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v47.0/composite/tree/DatedConversionRate/)

So it makes 307 redirect to the same URI.

Additionally, today stopped working integration of SFDX command line (and Visual Studio Code plugin) with this org.
When I am trying to make push/pull/open org I get nothing.  The command stays running forever without any error.

When I am trying to make auth

> sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com
>   I enter credentials ... and redirected back to login page without any error.
>   At the same time if I go to https://test.salesforce.com  page manually and enter login/password, everything works fine and I am logged in.

The only thing I found in logs of sfdx:

> {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"AuthInfo","level":20,"username":"test-q3rosalizsaj@example.com","orgId":"00D4E000000EKWGUA4","accessToken":"","refreshToken":"","instanceUrl":"https://nosoftware-efficiency-6832-dev-ed.cs83.my.salesforce.com","loginUrl":"https://CS83.salesforce.com","clientId":"PlatformCLI","createdOrgInstance":"CS83","created":"1577968426604","devHubUsername":"yuriy.peskov@curious-panda-wl62rz.com","isDevHub":false,"msg":"","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:30.731Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"AuthInfo","level":30,"msg":"Saved auth info for username: test-q3rosalizsaj@example.com","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:30.732Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"connection","level":20,"msg":"Connection refresh completed.","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:30.733Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"connection","level":20,"msg":" method=GET, url=https://nosoftware-efficiency-6832-dev-ed.cs83.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:30.733Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"connection","level":20,"msg":"elappsed time : 303msec","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:31.037Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"connection","level":20,"msg":" status=401, url=https://nosoftware-efficiency-6832-dev-ed.cs83.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:31.037Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"connection","level":20,"msg":"","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:31.037Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"AuthInfo","level":30,"msg":"Access token has expired. Updating...","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:31.037Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"crypto","level":20,"msg":"retryStatus: undefined","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:31.038Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"keyChain","level":20,"msg":"platform: darwin","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:31.039Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"sfdx","hostname":"NB192","pid":49599,"log":"AuthInfo","level":30,"msg":"Updated auth info for username: test-q3rosalizsaj@example.com","time":"2020-01-04T09:57:31.275Z","v":0}

but not sure to interpret it, but it is repeated forever if not to stop the cli command.

I would be very appreciate for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't what is was, but several days later everything is working fine again.  It looks like Salesforce had some issues there.